# Opencv install Error while using cmd

Tags: opencv, cmake, mingw32

I'm going to install opencv with cmake, and when I type mingw32-make in debug folder using cmd, this error appear, someone can help me?

```
 C:\opencv\sources\Built_with_Qt\debug>mingw32-make    
[  2%] Built target zlib     
[  6%] Built target libtiff    
[ 10%] Built target libjpeg    
[ 15%] Built target libwebp    
[ 19%] Built target libjasper    
[ 20%] Built target libpng    
[ 27%] Built target IlmImf      
[ 27%] Built target opencv_hal_pch_dephelp    
[ 27%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_hal     
[ 28%] Built target opencv_hal    
[ 28%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp    
[ 28%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core    
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_core300d.dll    
c:/progra~2/dev-cpp/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-   mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find - lRunTmChk    
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status    
mingw32-make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_core300d.dll] Error 1    
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2    
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/40159/cannot-compile-opencv-30/

Comment: @Peter: paraphrase the site and crate an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From http://answers.opencv.org/question/40159/cannot-compile-opencv-30/:

When using mingw32 you have to disable IPP. This can be done by unchecking `WITH_IPP` in the CMake-gui or by deleting ippicv from opencv\sources\3rdparty before running CMake. In any case, clean your cache by remove your CMakeCache.txt.